# Way to insert statement in oracle-db (Node-js)

Tags: node.js, database, reactjs, oracle, node-oracledb

I am developing a web application. I am encountering difficulties to construct a sql statement to insert in a table. Other statements like select are working. I utilized oracle db for the connection.

This is the snippet for creating insert statement

```
  async setAuditLogReprocessData( action, transaction_sequence, user) {

    const bindVars = {
      AUDIT_LOG_ID: AUDIT_LOG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
      AC: action,
      TRANSACTION_SEQUENCE: transaction_sequence,
      USER_ID: user
    };

    const sql = "AUDIT_LOG_ID, ACTION, TRANSACTION_SEQUENCE, USER_ID";

    let result;
    try {
      result = await this._database.simpleExecute(
        `INSERT INTO TABLE1 ${sql}
        VALUES (AUDIT_LOG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, AC, TRANSACTION_SEQUENCE, USER_ID)`,
        bindVars
      );
    } catch (err) {
      this._logger.error("Could not add audit trail.", err);
      throw new TxnError(500, `Audit Trail error. ${err.message}`);
    }

    return result;
```

This is the code for database.js

```
  simpleExecute(statement, binds = [], opts = {}) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      let conn;

      opts.outFormat = oracledb.OBJECT;
      opts.autoCommit = true;

      try {
        conn = await oracledb.getConnection();

        const result = await conn.execute(statement, binds, opts);
        resolve(result);
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      } finally {
        if (conn) { // conn assignment worked, need to close
          try {
            await conn.close();
          } catch (err) {
            this._server.getLogger().log(err);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it's helpful if you show the error message you're getting when you want help solving a problem. I'll take a shot at helping since there are some obvious mistakes.

First, you don't have any bind variables defined in your SQL statement. Bind variables are defined by putting a semicolon in front of the bind variable name. So your call to simpleExecute should look like this:

```
      result = await this._database.simpleExecute(
        `INSERT INTO TABLE1 ${sql}
        VALUES (AUDIT_LOG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :AC, :TRANSACTION_SEQUENCE, :USER_ID)`,
        bindVars
      );
```

Note that the statement above has three bind variables: AC, TRANSACTION_SEQUENCE, and USER_ID. I didn't make AUDIT_LOG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL a bind variable because the value you're inserting is supposed to come from the sequence.

I'm guessing you want the value that was inserted into the AUDIT_LOG_ID column. For that, you need to define an "out" bind variable (the default is in) and then use the RETURNING clause to get the value.

Your bind variable definition would look like this:

```
    const bindVars = {
      AUDIT_LOG_ID: {
        dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT,
        type: oracledb.NUMBER
      },
      AC: action,
      TRANSACTION_SEQUENCE: transaction_sequence,
      USER_ID: user
    };
```

Then you'd need to update your SQL to this:

```
      result = await this._database.simpleExecute(
        `INSERT INTO TABLE1 ${sql}
        VALUES (AUDIT_LOG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :AC, :TRANSACTION_SEQUENCE, :USER_ID)
        RETURNING AUDIT_LOG_ID into :AUDIT_LOG_ID`,
        bindVars 
      );
```

Try making those changes and let us know what you get.